# How to decompress .Snappy files in Hadoop HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, compression, snappy

I have some snappy compressed Snappy files in a directory in HDFS. I need to decompress each file and load into a Text file. Any Hadoop DFS commands are available? I am new here. Kindly help.

Thanks,
Praveen.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can achieve it is via -text hadoop command

> hadoop fs -text /hdfs_path/hdfs_file.snappy > some_unix_file.txt
>
> hadoop fs -put some_unix_file.txt /hdfs_path